# Why can't I use SynchronizedCollection when I include System.Collections.Generic?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to include the following line in my C# code, but for some reason it's being marked as an error:

```
        public SynchronizedCollection<Uri> allImages = new SynchronizedCollection<Uri>();
```

I've tried including `using System.Collections.Generic` but it does not resolve the issue. Any idea how I can get a `SynchronizedCollection<T>` working in my application?

Comment: Are you getting an error? Runtime or compile? what is the error? Did you try google? Did you try : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668265(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you look at the documentation you will see it states

> **Namespace:**   System.Collections.Generic
>   **Assembly:**  System.ServiceModel (in System.ServiceModel.dll)

This means that although it is in the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace you need to make sure you have the `System.ServiceModel.dll` dll [included in your project as a refrence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx) to be able to use the class.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it for me.